# How can I detect circle by using openCV in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect circle in a picture by using haar cascade. I created an cascade xml.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("C://OpenCVcascade//resimler//coins.jpg")
circles_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C://Cascade//dairetanima.xml")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = circles_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 1)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for (x, y, w, h) in circles:
        center = (x + w // 2, y + h // 2)
        radius = (w + h) // 4
        cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My result:
[image]

I already know, there are different method to detect circle. But I am trying to do with cascade method. Because after this part, I will use it for real time detection.

Comment: Try this link https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/

Comment: I already looked this link. I was trying to do it with cascade method. But I guess, we use cascade method to find specific objects likes car,hand,human. Circle is just a shape. So cascade method is not suitable to detect circle or another shape. Thanks.